# Split matches in regex

Tags: regex, split

Having this string:

> Paquete Trend Exterior -alfombrillas, faros antiniebla, llantas de
>   aleación de 15- (300), Paquete Winter -asientos delanteros
>   calefactables, parabrisas térmico- (300), Paquete City -control de
>   aparcamiento trasero, retrovisores plegables eléctricamente- (250).

I tried this reg expression:

```
 /.\*-.\*- \\(.*\\)/
```

To get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paquete Trend Exterior -alfombrillas, faros antiniebla, llantas de aleación de 15- (300)
            [1] => Paquete Winter -asientos delanteros calefactables, parabrisas térmico- (300)
            [2] => Paquete City -control de aparcamiento trasero, retrovisores plegables eléctricamente- (250)
        )    
)
```

But i'm having this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paquete Trend Exterior -alfombrillas, faros antiniebla, llantas de aleación de 15- (300), Paquete Winter -asientos delanteros calefactables, parabrisas térmico- (300), Paquete City -control de aparcamiento trasero, retrovisores plegables eléctricamente- (250)
        )
)
```

How can i split the results?

---

### EXTRA

String given could be like this too:

```
Bola de remolque desmontable (350 euros), control de velocidad -mega, chachi- (150), cristales traseros tintados (120), pintura blanco sólido (150), Paquete Titanium Cuero -llantas de aleación de 17, tapicería de cuero, asientos delanteros calefactables- (600), Paquete Panorámico -techo solar panorámico, cristales tintados- (600).
```

And id like to match the "Bola de remolque desmontable (350 euros)" format also. Is it possible?

Comment: In what programming language are you using the regex?

Comment: Actually i'm using this page to test... http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php , type: perl

Comment: I don't think you have to escape the `-`.

Comment: yea you're right sebas

Comment: Try changing `.*` to `[^-]*` since `.` technically can match `-` Example: http://regexr.com?355dg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the the `*` is greedy, thus it will match as much of the string as possible. You can just make the `*` non-greedy, as in `*?`.

Thus:

```
/.*?-.*?- \(.*?\)/
```

Prints:

```
[0] => Paquete Trend Exterior -alfombrillas, faros antiniebla, llantas de aleación de 15- (300)
[1] => , Paquete Winter -asientos delanteros calefactables, parabrisas térmico- (300)
[2] => , Paquete City -control de aparcamiento trasero, retrovisores plegables eléctricamente- (250)
```

If you want the `,` to be removed as well, consider making the first character `\w`, if this is generic enough (`[^, ]` instead of `\w` will also work).

```
/\w.*?-.*?- \(.*?\)/
```

Prints:

```
[0] => Paquete Trend Exterior -alfombrillas, faros antiniebla, llantas de aleación de 15- (300)
[1] => Paquete Winter -asientos delanteros calefactables, parabrisas térmico- (300)
[2] => Paquete City -control de aparcamiento trasero, retrovisores plegables eléctricamente- (250)
```

**For the second string**

You could make `-.*?-` optional by surrounding it in brackets and putting a `?` after it (the `?:` just makes it a non-capturing group, so it doesn't output that as well, it doesn't change the matching).

```
/\w.*?(?:-.*?-)? \(.*?\)/
```

Or you could do something simpler which would work for both strings:

```
/\w.*?\)/
```

Comment: Note that the `\(.*?\)` will match non numeric characters too, so if you would have brackets in the title, for example: `Paquete Winter (extra thick)` then it'll split from there.

Comment: Thank you all, now the reality is a little more complicated as i edited above.

Comment: @Rimbuaj For the second one, something a little simpler could work - `/[^, ].*?\)/` (also works for the first one).

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of this one?

```
/.*?\(\d+\)[,\.]/
```

http://www.debuggex.com/r/ArLYC3VNceye7z9A

Comment: I actually don't want to match the coma between every result

Comment: It matches a comma or a dot, you can of course leave it off: `/.*?\(\d+\)/` will still match

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to:

```
/.*?-.*?- \(.*?\)/
```

`*?` matches zero or more times, but unlike `*`, it matches as few times as possible.

In your version, the first `.*` matches everything up to `Paquete City`.

Read http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html for more information.

You could also use:

```
/[^-]*-[^-]*- \([^\)]*\)/
```

It's usually a good idea to be more specific about what can match, rather than using `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split by `(?<=[(]\d+( euros)?[)]), +`.

Comment: Thank you, now the reality is a little more complicated as i edited above

Answer (score 0):

Here -> http://regexr.com?355dp

RegExp: `/[^, ][^(]*[(][0-9]*[)]/g`
pattern: `[^, ][^(]*[(][0-9]*[)]`

Comment: I actually don't want to match the coma between every result

Comment: Thank you, now the reality is a little more complicated as i edited above